# DnsQuery_A : Get all DNS entries in system using Windows kernel routine

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel-module, win32-process, windows-kernel

I am trying to  Get all DNS entries on system using some Windows kernel routine did not find is there kernel mode any routine for it.
I know there is user mode API DnsQuery_A/W where I can go iterating over each record using next pointer

Comment: If you're looking for a kernel analog to DnsQuery in general there is [WskGetAddressInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wsk/nc-wsk-pfn_wsk_get_address_info)

Comment: @Luke actually I was looking Windows kernel equivalent of DnsGetCacheDataTable in Windows kernel

Comment: I highly doubt such functionality exists as DNS cache is maintained in user mode.